# ¿Como puedo realizar varias operaciones sobre un mismo atributo?

Tags: java

```
public class MiNumero {
private int Valor;
private int NumSuma;
private int NumResta;

public int getNumResta() {
    return NumResta;
}

public void setNumResta(int numResta) {
    NumResta = numResta;
}

public int getValor() {
    return Valor;
}

public void setValor(int valor) {
    Valor = valor;
}

public int getNumSuma() {
    return NumSuma;
}

public void setNumSuma(int numSuma) {
    NumSuma = numSuma;
}

public MiNumero() {
    this.Valor = 0;
}

public MiNumero(int Valor) {
    this.Valor = 10;
}

public int suma(int NumSuma) {
    return Valor + NumSuma;
}

public int resta(int NumResta) {
    return Valor - NumResta;
 }
}
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MiNumeroApp {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    MiNumero a = new MiNumero();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(a.getValor());
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero para sumar:");
    a.setNumSuma(sc.nextInt());     
    System.out.println(a.suma(a.getNumSuma()));
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero para restar:");
    a.setNumResta(sc.nextInt());
    System.out.println(a.resta(a.getNumResta()));
 }
}
```

¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Escribe en Java una clase llamada MiNumero

- Método suma(int): permite sumar una cantidad al número
- Metodo resta(int): permite restar una cantidad al número
- Método getValor() devuelve el valor actual del número(el resultado de haber realizado una suma y despues una resta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que has hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Tengo esto hasta ahora

Comment: ok y cual es exactamente el problema?

Comment: Cuando realizó la suma y después la resta no me da el valor correcto, si valor = 10, NumSuma=90 y NunResta = 30 la operación me tendría que dar 70

Comment: Te diste cuenta que en el método `resta()` no estas restando si no sumando?

Comment: Lo acabo de corregir y sigue sin darme el resultado que quiero

Comment: Cual es el resultado que quieres?

Comment: imaginate que hago la siguiente operacion: Valor + NunSuma y al resultado de esa operacion le resto NunResta. He añadido una imagen para que veas la operacion que realizo y el resultado que me da

Comment: Cual es el valor que deseas obtener en esa operacion?

Comment: Para los atributos valor = 10, NunSuma=90 y NunResta=30, quiero que el valor de esas operaciones me de 70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solucion

Al realizar las operaciones no obtienes los valores que quieres ya que en los métodos `suma()` y `resta()` solo estas retornando el resultado de la operación, pero no estas almacenando ese valor en ninguna variable. Por eso siempre obtienes el valor inicial de la variable Valor, ya que en ningún momento le asignas el valor de la suma y la resta. Para lograr lo que quieres, almacena el valor de las operaciones en la variable `Valor`, de esa manera obtendrás el resultado que quieres.

```
public int suma(int NumSuma) {
    // Realizas la operación y le asignas el resultado
    // a la variable Valor
    return Valor = Valor + NumSuma;
}

public int resta(int NumResta) {
    // Realizas la operación y le asignas el resultado
    // a la variable Valor
    return Valor = Valor - NumResta;
}
```

### Errores lógicos

En tu código tienes varios errores de lógica y no estas aplicando las mejores practicas. Me costo poder encontrar los constructores de tu clase `MiNumero`, ya que no los declaraste al principio. El constructor debe ser el primer o los primeros métodos que declares en tu clase, recuerda que el constructor es el método de entrada de un objeto, el primero en ejecutarse.

#### Constructores

Otra cosa, en el constructor que recibe el parámetro `Valor`, no le estas asignando el valor que recibe a nada, si no que a la variable `Valor` le estas asignando un valor estático, no se si lo haces intencionalmente o si de verdad es un error. No tiene lógica que declares un constructor que reciba un parámetro y el valor de ese parámetro no se lo asignes a nada. También, no es necesario que inicialices la variable `Valor` con `0`, el valor por defecto de una variable de tipo int es `0`.

Incorrecto ❌

```
// El parámetro que recibe no se lo estas 
// asignando a nada
public MiNumero(int Valor) {    
    this.Valor = 0;
}
```

Correcto ✔

```
// El parámetro que recibe se lo asignas a 
// la variable Valor 
public MiNumero(int Valor) {
    this.Valor = Valor;
}
```

#### Variables

Por convención los nombres de las variables deben comenzar con minúscula y aquí estas declarando todas las variables con mayúscula. A demás de que es incorrecto, es incomodo de leer y genera confusión.

Incorrecto ❌

```
private int Valor;
private int NumSuma;
```

Correcto ✔

```
private int valor;
private int numSuma;
```

---

En fin, tu código debería de verse así:

```
 public class MiNumero {

    private int valor;
    private int numSuma;
    private int numResta;

    public MiNumero() {}

    public MiNumero(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    // METODO GET Y SET
    ...

    public int suma(int numSuma) {
        return valor = valor + numSuma;
    }

    public int resta(int numResta) {
        return valor = valor - numResta;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me has resuelto mi duda y encima me has explicado y corregido un par de errores, de verdad te lo agradezco mucho, no te puedes imaginar lo agradecido que me siento